# vmware vsan failures to tolerate

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-vsan

I'm migrating from an Solaris iSCSI backend in my lab to vSAN. I having difficulty understanding vSAN redundancy.

I would like to configure a cluster to survive a host/disk failure. I know that "stripe width" and "failures to tolerate" are related settings. But, I'm unclear if this requires vSAN enterprise or will standard do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Standard will do the trick!

Enterprise := Standard + 
( Deduplication & Compression ) + 
( RAID-5/6 Erasure Coding ) + 
( Stretched Cluster ) + 
( QoS IOPS Limits )

https://www.vmware.com/content/dam/digitalmarketing/vmware/en/pdf/products/vsan/vmware-vsan-65-licensing-guide.pdf